# Probability: Pick a random real number between 11.3 and 23.3

Tags: probability

Pick a random real number between 11.3 and 23.3
Find :

- a)The probability that the number will be exactly 13
- b)The probability that the number will be between 13 and 15, inclusive
- c)The probability that the number will be between 13 and 15, exclusive
- d)The probability that the number will be less than 13 or greater than
  15
- e)The probability that the number will be less than 15 or greater than
  13

Is it correct to assume that the number of numbers in the range are
   12? Then for question A, 3/12=0.25

- This seems wrong. I know im missing something because a real number
  between 11.3 and 23.3 can be 11.44 or 13.35 etc.

How do you approach this question? I have been getting some wrong answers and i am confused.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed some of your attempts it would be easier to give advice.

Comment: First we need to make an assumption, that the guess will be a uniformly distributed random variable.  With that assumption, we can say that someone will "almost never" choose 13.  All of the questions can be answered using the same method,  compare the measure of the interval in the question to the measure of the interval [11.3, 22.3]

Comment: Use geometric probability(I think).

Comment: (e) is presumably $1$

Comment: @DougM  15-13/ 23.3 - 11.3 Thats is what i was doing. Apparently the question says round to 4 SF but accepts the answer in 3 dec places... crazy

Comment: "Is it correct to assume that the number of numbers in the range are 12?" Why would you assume that?  It says *real* number.  There are infinitely many real numbers betwee $11.3$ and $23.3$.  And why did you say *three* over $12$.  There is only *one* number that is exactly $13$.  So the probability will be $\frac 1{\infty} = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a):

There's only $1$ possible way to get $13$, and there are infinite real numbers between $11.3$ and $23.3$, so that will be $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$.

For b):

The answer will be:

$\frac{\text{The amount of length taken up by the interval }13\text{ to }15}{\text{The length of the entire interval}}=\frac{2}{12}=\frac{1}{6}$

For c):

The answer is the same as b) because if you take out $2$ numbers(in this case, $13$ and $15$) out of the interval, there are still infinitely many numbers to choose from, so taking out $13$ and $15$ won't really change the probability.

For d):

You want the number to be between $11.3$ and $13$ and between $15$ and $23.3$. The interval $11.3$ to $13$ takes up a length of $13-11.3=1.7$, and the interval $15$ to $23.3$ takes up a length of $23.3-15=8.3$. That means that the probability is:

$\frac{1.7+8.3}{10}=\frac{10}{12}=\frac{5}{6}$

For e):

If the number is less than $15$ or greater than $13$, that means that the number can be any real number, so the probability is $1$.

(Note: I'm only in the eighth grade so I'm not too sure if my answer is correct)

Comment: pretty good for the eighth grade!  another way to look at c) is that the length of the interval $[13,15]$ which you used for b) and the length of the interval $(13,15)$ are both the same length of $2$. A "point is that with has no part" (paraphrasing Euclid) means points have to width so leaving out $2$ points won't change the length of a interval.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment! I haven't thought of it that way before. Thanks for sharing this way of thinking with me. Also, I just learned about this in my school so that's how I knew how to do the problem.